# How to install Windows 7 from MS-DOS?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, installation, ms-dos

Before, I can copy Windows XP CD contents to D:\windowsxp, then

- Boot DOS CD
- > format C: /s /q
- > D:\windowsxp\i386\winnt.exe

How to install Windows 7 from MS-DOS? I found install from USB only.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure why you're booting DOS from a CD, but won't boot Windows 7 from a CD...

Having said that, Windows Vista and newer no longer use DOS during its initial setup, instead opting to use Windows Preinstallation Environment (PE).  There is a much more [involved setup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749311%28WS.10%29.aspx), requiring that you create a Windows PE image in advance before you can [boot it from the Hard Drive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722114%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Because Win7 comes on a DVD, not CD.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t. The install process was completely changed in Vista.

Comment: What changed about it?

Comment: @SimonSheehan, um, everything. Like Powerlord said, the installer is no longer a DOS executable, it is a Windows program that runs from a copy of Windows PE (like a Linux “live cd”). The Windows installer runs a stripped-down version of Windows which then loads the installer program itself; sort of like installing a newer version of Windows while booted into an older version.

Answer (score 1):

```
It is not possible to run Vista and Windows 7 installer from command prompt.
```

when you will try to run it from command mode then it will give error like win32 application will not run in dost mode. (not exactly this).

Windows Preinstallation Environment (PE) may be alternate to do this in dos mode. but according to setup program behavior of windows 7; i do not think it can be achieved easily.. need lots of hard work.

```
USB Install is much easy with Win2Flash. nice stuff. it is great alternate.
```

you can look for these stuff :

[Install Windows 7 or Windows Vista on a Pc Without DVD Media](http://forums.techarena.in/tips-tweaks/1093383.htm)

[How to Install Windows 7 FAST without a DVD or USB Device](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/7943-install-windows-7-fast-without-dvd-usb-device.html)

Answer (score 0):

*Install through the bootable Windows 7 DVD or by making Bootable USB-drive for Windows 7 by any software like Win2Flash.

Answer (score 0):

- Create the Bootable OS media in the pen drive.
  download the “Windows 7* USB 3.0 Creator Utility” from any other system. ( link : https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25476/Windows-7-USB-3-0-Creator-Utility )

  1. Download and unzip the Windows 7 USB 3.0 Creator utility to a temporary folder on the Admin system.
  2. Connect the USB device containing the Windows 7 image to the Admin system.
  3. Double-click the file Installer_Creator.exe to run the utility.
  4. Browse to the root of the USB drive.
  5. Click Create Image to begin the creation process.
  6. Wait for the process to finish. It can take up to 15 minutes.
- Once the USB drivers are incorporated in the OS media, connect it with the system where the OS has to be installed and make the necessary changes in BIOS to start the installation process.